# Assembly code that returns the sum of the even digits of a number

Tags: loops, assembly, x86-64, nasm, number-formatting

```
global main
section .data
msgeven db "The sum of the even digits in the number is:",0
sum db 0
uc db 0
c db 0
num db 234



section .text


main:

mov ax,[num]
_calculatesum:
cmp ax,'0'

je calculate_sum_done
mov r8b,10
div r8b
mov [uc],ah
mov[c],al

xor ebx,ebx
mov bl,[uc]
test bl,1
jnz _skip_odd_digit
mov cl,[sum]
add cl,bl

_skip_odd_digit:
jmp _calculatesum


calculate_sum_done:
add cl,'0'
mov [sum],cl
mov rax,1
mov rdi,1
mov rsi,msgeven
mov rdx,50
syscall

mov rax,1
mov rdi,1
mov rsi,sum
mov rdx,1
syscall

mov rax,60
mov rdi,0
syscall
```

I have this assembly code that should return the sum of the even digits in num, in this case 6, but although I can run the program I get this The sum of the even digits in the number is:00�0  and i don't really know how to solve this error

Comment: Please [edit] your question and use the code button on the toolbar to fix the formatting. Your loop is broken in multiple ways. For starters, the `cmp ax, '0'` is using ascii comparison. Then you reload `sum` every time. Also you do not clear `ah` so it will be part of the dividend in the next iteration. PS: learn to use a debugger to single step the code so you can see what goes wrong.

Comment: And of course `num db 234` is wrong too, it should be `dw`

Comment: If i define num as word, is ax the right register to use in this case?

Comment: `je calculate_sum_done
mov r8b,10
div r8b
mov [uc],ah
mov[c],al
mov al,0
mov ah,0

xor ebx,ebx
mov bl,[uc]
test bl,1
jnz _skip_odd_digit
add cl,bl

_skip_odd_digit:
jmp _calculatesum

calculate_sum_done:
add cl,'0'
mov [sum],cl` this is how I undesrtood i should modify the code

Comment: That forces `ax` to be zero for the next iteration. You want to keep `al` unchanged. Using `c`, `uc` and `sum` is just adding confusion for no benefit.  PS: using 8 bit arithmetic the largest number you can handle is `2559` which may or may not match your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> The sum of the even digits in the number is:00�0
> ```

You are printing too many characters to the screen. The *msgeven* text has 44 characters, so you should not be using `mov rdx,50` in your syscall. Solve this with:

```
msgeven db  "The sum of the even digits in the number is:"
length  equ $ - msgeven

...

mov  edx, length
syscall
```

What you currently output as the result, does not reflect the calculation that is going on:

- You forget to update the *sum* variable and thus only the very last digit will make it (somewhat) to the result. The best solution does not need to use the *sum* variable at all. See below.
- It is most probable for the loop to run for too long since your loop-ending-condition is `cmp ax,'0'` which is the same as `cmp ax, 48` and not at all the test for zero that is needed.
- The size error on `mov ax,[num]` for the byte-sized variable is probably harmless as it would have loaded a zero in AH.

### A solution

```
num     db  234
msgeven db  "The sum of the even digits in the number is: "
result  db  "??"
length  equ $ - msgeven

  ...

  movzx eax, byte [num]
  mov   ebx, 10          ; CONST divider
  xor   ecx, ecx         ; Result
.CalculateSum:
  xor   edx, edx
  div   ebx              ; EDX:EAX / EBX  --> EAX is quotient
  test  dl, 1            ;                --> EDX is remainder
  jnz   .SkipOddDigit
  add   ecx, edx
.SkipOddDigit:
  test  eax, eax
  jnz   .CalculateSum
```

For your test case number 234 the result is 6 and that is just a single character, so adding '0' would be sufficient. However, the biggest result that you can expect is the **2**-character number 16 coming from test case number 88.

```
  mov   eax, ' '
  cmp   cl, 10
  jb    .OneChar
  add   eax, 17        ; -> AL='1'
  sub   ecx, 10
.OneChar:
  mov   [result], al
  add   cl, '0'
  mov   [result + 1], cl

  mov   edx, length
  mov   rsi, msgeven
  mov   edi, 1
  mov   eax, 1
  syscall
```